# Square Sitting Arrangement

Tags: logical-deduction

Eight people i.e., J, K, L, M, N, O, P and Q sit around a square-shaped table. Four people sit at the four corners of the table and face outside the table. Four people sit at the middle of the four sides and face inside the table. Only one person sits between J and Q who sits at the middle of the side. K sits third to the left of Q. M sits second to the right of K. Two people sit between M and O. L sits second to the right of N.

Where is each person sitting?

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling, take our [tour]! Could you please provide [proper attribution](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7259/proper-attribution-for-non-original-puzzles-a-guide) for this question?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the seating arrangement:

> [image: 1]

The explanation:

> WLOG, place Q facing inwards at the top side of the table (viewed from above). K, being third to Q's left, is facing outwards in the bottom right corner. M, sitting second to K's right, is in the bottom left corner. Since two people sit between M and O, O must be sitting on the right side of the table, and since only one person sits between Q and J, J must be at the left side of the table. L sits second to the right of N, which is only possible if they are sitting at the top two corners, and P is placed in the only remaining seat at the bottom.

Comment: Please do not answer questions which are off-topic per our [attribution policy](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7259/proper-attribution-for-non-original-puzzles-a-guide); that policy is in place to prevent cheating and plagiarism. (In particular this question follows a pattern of copy-pasting poor-quality questions off of Indian banking-exam test-prep sites)